# MS SQL Server 2012 extremely slow information_schema query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance

We are using MS SQL Server 2012 , we have this extremely slow query that selects data from the information_schema , after some analysis we found that the root cause of the slowness is a join that selects from the KEY_COLUMN_USAGE view .

I tried to select the count from that view using the following statement :

**select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE**

and it took 7 hrs to return the result (About 75 000 rows ) .

This is only happening on one of the databases , on the other databases (on the same server )  , the same query takes less than 3 seconds !

What might be the root cause of this ?

Comment: You don't provide any information so it's impossible to answer. Were you running anything on that database? Was your query blocked for 7 hours perhaps, while something else was running? The Activity Monitor would show which queries were blocked by what

Comment: BTW 75000 key usages is a rather large number. Someone was bound to use at least one database table at every moment during working hours. Which means that your query may never had the chance to acquire the necessary locks until people stopped using the database

Comment: Its a local database ( non-production ) so no-body is issuing quires against it , i have checked sp_who2; and other quires and it shows that the query is not blocked (BlkBy is empty ) however it is showing that lots of IO Read operation included  .